# how to delete the empty of array and just show array if value is not null and show it to user

Tags: javascript

I have some question about this problem, and I still not found the way and I wanna ask in here. Okay for the problem is I wanna delete all my empty array and not show into user view and just show the not empty array, like this for the code and result :

```js
const objectFruits = [
    {fruits: 'apple'},
    {fruits: 'banana'},
    {fruits: 'strawberry'},
    {fruits: 'manggo'},
];

const objectMyFavorite = [
    {fruits: 'apple'},
    {fruits: 'apple'},
    {fruits: 'banana'},
];

const getAllFruits = { fruits: objectFruits.map(item => item.fruits) }
const getAllMyFavorite = { fruits: objectMyFavorite.map(item => item.fruits) }

let myView = '';

for (let i = 0; i < getAllFruits['fruits'].length; i++) {
    const nameFruits = getAllFruits['fruits'][i];
    const filterMyFavorite = getAllMyFavorite['fruits'].filter(function (fruitss) {
        return fruitss == nameFruits
    });
    // and how I delete the empty and just show array if value is not null and show it to user
    myView += `
        <p>${filterMyFavorite.length == 0 ? `delete this array and delete this row and not show in user view` : `is not empty => expected (apple, apple) and (banana)`}</p>
    `;
}

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = myView
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>test</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="test">
        
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I make a some mistake in my word you can direct again to me, thank you

Comment: You cannot delete arrays but you can hide them from the user view.

Comment: what anything about that, I just wanna show my row is not empty array sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're too close for the solution. Check whether the below code fulfills your task:

```js
const objectFruits = [{
    fruits: 'apple'
  },
  {
    fruits: 'banana'
  },
  {
    fruits: 'strawberry'
  },
  {
    fruits: 'manggo'
  },
];

const objectMyFavorite = [{
    fruits: 'apple'
  },
  {
    fruits: 'apple'
  },
  {
    fruits: 'banana'
  },
];

const getAllFruits = {
  fruits: objectFruits.map(item => item.fruits)
}
const getAllMyFavorite = {
  fruits: objectMyFavorite.map(item => item.fruits)
}

let myView = '';

for (let i = 0; i < getAllFruits['fruits'].length; i++) {
  const nameFruits = getAllFruits['fruits'][i];
  const filterMyFavorite = getAllMyFavorite['fruits'].filter(function(fruitss) {
    return fruitss == nameFruits
  });
  // and how I delete the empty and just show array if value is not null and show it to user

    if (filterMyFavorite.length > 0){
      myView += `<p>${filterMyFavorite}</p>`
   }
}

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = myView
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>test</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="test">

  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the advice sir, but this method give me more space row in the user view, and I wanna delete that row how can I do that?

Comment: did you mean the space between "apple, apple" and "banana"?

Comment: well when the condition is else, the row is giving some space between the data, for example if the `"apple, apple"` is empty and for the first row is `banana` (if `"apple, apple"` is not empty this row will be second posisition) and before accessing `banana` row, the result is giving a space for a empty condition

Answer (score 1):

You can append to `myView` only if the value is valid:

```
if (filterMyFavorite.length > 0) {
  myView += `
     <p>Add  item here</p>
    `;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple conditional:

```js
  ...
  if (filterMyFavorite.length !== 0) {
    myView += "<p>" + filterMyFavorite.join(",") + "</p>";
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment you can't delete the array, but you can hide it - try this:

```
if(filterMyFavorite.length > 0) {
    filterMyFavorite.map(f => { myView += `<p>${f}</p>` })
}
```